# Why I get a Null Exception in this?

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to fill an Array String in the next code.

```
public void setArray_name_venues(List<Venue> list) {
        // storing string resources into Array
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            this.name_venues[i] = "" + list.get(i).getName();
        }
    }
```

I use a Asynhttp client, and I call this method con the onFinish method.

```
public void getVenues() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(getQueryVenues4SQ(), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onFinish();

                File log2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"venlist.txt");

                try {
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log2.getAbsolutePath(),false));
                    for(int i = 0; i < getListCategories().size(); i++){
                        out.write(listVenues.get(i).toString());
                    }
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setArray_name_venues(listVenues);
                        Log.i("ArrayVenues", getArray_name_venues().toString());
                        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
                        customListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_venues, name_venues));

                    }
                });

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        makeToast("Nightclubs cargados", 1);
                    }
                });
            }
```

It fails in the setArray_name_venues(listVenues).

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

"name_venues" is on a "String[] name_venues" variable at the start of public class MainActivity, before the oncreate method.

Logcat:

```
05-30 14:24:14.645: W/dalvikvm(21040): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410652a0)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at victor.martin.loc4sq.MainActivity.setArray_name_venues(MainActivity.java:100)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at victor.martin.loc4sq.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:271)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at victor.martin.loc4sq.MainActivity$2.onFinish(MainActivity.java:269)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:194)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:123)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$1.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:84)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
05-30 14:24:14.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21040):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Posting the log cat would be helpful to see exactly where

Comment: Where is `name_venues[]` declared?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public void setArray_name_venues(List<Venue> list) {
    name_venues = new String[list.size()];
    // storing string resources into Array
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        this.name_venues[i] = "" + list.get(i).getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Woow! That's it. I belived that Strings don't need to reserve space!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if name_venues[i] is a list then its a wrong way of using it you can directly assign list parameter object to it, if name_venues[i] is String array and you have just declared it as String name_venues[]; then it will give you null exception when you try using its index so add the following statement before for.

```
name_venues=new String[list.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code included or debugging information provided to determine the likely cause of the exception. One possibility is that your `listVenues` list is null or one of it's elements it null.

If `getListCategories().size()` is zero, then the for loop that writes our `listVenues` to the *venlist.txt* log file would never access the list so you wouldn't know about the null pointer until the `setArray_name_venues` call.

Is that *venlist.txt* file empty by any chance?

Otherwise, add some more logging to your code. It should at least become obvious exactly where the null is coming from. Once you know that, it'll be easier to figure out how to fix it.